# The format function looping over a dotted alist

Tags: common-lisp

I am working on a function that transforms an alist into a query parameters. So far it looks like this.

```
(defun encode-options (opts)
  "Turns an alist into url query parameters."
  (format nil "~{~{~A=~A~}~^&~}" opts))
```

This works perfectly for alists like `((a b) (c d))` (Resulting in `"A=B&C=D"`), but fails for dotted alists like `((a . b) (c . d))`. (Resulting in `The value B is not of type LIST.`)

My question is: **Is it possible to `format` the dotted alist to give me the expected results and how?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to format the dotted alist?

No, format iterates over proper lists.

There are many possible ways to implement what you want. Here I present two of them.

#### Keep control string, change data

```
(defun ensure-proper-list (value)
  (typecase value
    (null nil)
    (cons (cons (car value)
                (ensure-proper-list (cdr value))))
    (t (list value))))
```

Now, you transform the option argument so that all elements are proper lists:

```
(defun encode-options (options)
  "Turns an alist into url query parameters."
  (format nil
          "~{~{~A=~A~}~^&~}"
          (mapcar #'ensure-proper-list options)))
```

#### Keep data, change control string

```
(defun print-alist (stream data &optional colonp atsignp)
  (declare (ignore colonp atsignp))
  (destructuring-bind (head . tail) data
    (format stream "~A=~A" head (if (consp tail) (first tail) tail))))
```

With this new format control, print the list as given:

```
(defun encode-options (options)
  "Turns an alist into url query parameters."
  (format nil
          "~{~/lib:print-alist/~^&~}"
          options))
```

Note that I added a package prefix `lib` because without a package, `print-alist` would be looked up in the user package (a.k.a. COMMON-LISP-USER), which in my opinion is rarely what you want. From [22.3.5.4 Tilde Slash: Call Function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_ced.htm):

> The function corresponding to a ~/name/ directive is obtained by
>   looking up the symbol that has the indicated name in the indicated
>   package. If name does not contain a ":" or "::", then the whole name
>   string is looked up in the COMMON-LISP-USER package.

That's why I would recommend to always mention the package with `~/` directives.